# php upload file error #8 when it's a linux executable

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian

I have a form with works well (upload) for many files (tgz, microsoft executables, macosx executables) and with diferente size (included bigger than the ones that gives me error).

So no files size, ... is the problem.

But when I try to upload a file (linux exe 32bits) to my debian (squeeze) 64bits with apache  (apache 2.2.16) I allways get error #8 which is the UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION error.

The php (php 5.3.3) $_FILES array gives me 'size'==0, no 'tmp_name' and the correct 'name'.

My form is like that :

```
<form action=\"emUpload_file.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
```

Any ideas?.

Thanks.

The load is handled ok because it works when I upload any other kind of files, I only have troubles with a file that is a linux executable . For me this is weird , but I think it's not a problem on my html/php code.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the code that handles the upload.

Comment: from the PHP website: UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with phpinfo() may help. Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.  So figure out which extension is stopping it...  http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've found the problem about uploading an executable (linux) to my apache server (linux) .
The development were done in a different server that production one, and this one had an extra module for security it is the Suhosin .

By now I have just deleted the /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini , restarted the server and the error 8 has gone.

Thanks.